# Find folders/documents in Google Drive shared outside the organization?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

For security reasons we'd like to see all documents in Google Drive which are shared with people outside the organization (Google Apps users). Is this possible? I know you can search for "to:[email]" but this requires knowing the exact email, we want "to:[non apps user]".

Comment: Good question. Too bad it hasn't been answered yet. I've love to know how to view a list of Google Drive items which are shared with the public or shared outside of the Google Apps organization? Can Google Drive users easily search for items which have a sharing setting like "Public on the Web" or "Anyone with the link".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google Apps does not natively support reporting on who has access to what in Google Drive. The report you are looking for is possible through a Google Apps script.

As you probably know, from the `Reports` section of your Google Apps admin panel, you will be able to tell *how many* files are externally visible.

If you are on the Google Apps Unlimited or Google Apps for Education license, you will have access to a [Drive audit log](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579696?hl=en), from which you may be able to generate a report based on sharing events. This could be cumbersome.

If you have a $30 to $40 USD budget, you can either procure the [Drive Audit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drive-audit/hgmppaidmppjfpcdfehmcajkbpbnbgph) Google Sheet Add-on or the [Drive Privacy script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-drive-access/28237/) from tech blogger Amit Agarwal and produce the report.

[image: Drive Privacy script screenshot]

A free option based on Stefan Lasiewski's suggestion below is to try [whohasaccess.com](https://whohasaccess.com/). The app requires `View and manage the files in your Google Drive` permissions, among other simpler permissions.

Comment: There is also https://whohasaccess.com/ . The app requires `View and manage the files in your Google Drive` permissions, among other simpler permissions. Also see http://lifehacker.com/whohasaccess-shows-you-who-still-has-permissions-to-you-1617622146